# JSP expression language not working

Tags: jsp, spring-mvc, spring-3

I am not able to get `${}` expression working on my `.jsp` page.

**displayAllCustomers.jsp**

```
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c" %>


<html>
    <body>
        <h3>Our Entire Customer Database</h3>
        <ul>
            <c:forEach items="${allCustomers}" var="customer">
                <li>${customer.name}</li>
            </c:forEach>
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

**dispatcher-servlet.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
    xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
        xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans 
                                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.0.xsd
                                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx
                                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.0.xsd
                                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop 
                                      http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.0.xsd">

    <import resource="applicationContext.xml"/>     

    <bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">
        <property name="prefix" value="/WEB-INF/views/" />
        <property name="suffix" value=".jsp" />
    </bean>


    <bean name="/displayAllCustomers" class="mypackage.DisplayAllCustomersController">
        <property name="customerManagementService" ref="customerManagementService" />
    </bean>     

</beans>
```

**DisplayAllCustomersController.java**

```
public class DisplayAllCustomersController {

    private CustomerManagementService customerManagementService;
    public void setCustomerManagementService(CustomerManagementService customerManagementService) {
        this.customerManagementService = customerManagementService;
    }

    @RequestMapping("/displayAllCustomers")
    public ModelAndView displayAllCustomers() {
        List<Customer> allCustomers = customerManagementService.getAllCustomers();
        return new ModelAndView("displayAllCustomers", "allCustomers", allCustomers);
    }
}
```

I am getting only the header "Our Entire Customer Database" displayed when I get the page displayed.

It's driving me nuts and I cant figure out what I am missing.

Could someone please help me understand why is it happening?

Many thanks.

Comment: Your title conflicts with the problem description. If taglibs/EL was not working you would have seen them raw in the generated HTML output by rightclick > *View Source* in webbrowser. Is this true? What do you see in the generated HTML output? Do you see `<c:forEach>` or not? Do you see `${customer.name}` or not? And what if you put `${allCustomers}` plain inside `<h3>`?

Comment: @BalusC: I din't know that I had mistakenly imported the `ModelAndView` class from the `org.springframework.web.portlet.portal` package or I wouldnt have had that title for the problem I was having. But you're right.

Answer (score 9):

Add the following to the top

```
<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Comment: Added `<%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>` on the top but still it does not work. I am getting all the data from database as I checked it by printing it on console but I am not able to display it.

Comment: Could you try the below two, what is the output <%= request.getAttribute("allCustomers") %> ${allCustomers}

Comment: `<%= request.getAttribute("allCustomers") %>` shows `null` and `${allCustomers}` shows nothing just like it shouldn't. Where is `allCustomers` getting lost in the `Model` passed on to the `displayAllCustomers.jsp` view?

Comment: If I add this, I'm getting the raw html text seen on my browser. Any body facing this issue?

Comment: what is the version attribute of your web-app tag in web.xml? It should be something like this : <web-app xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd"
         version="3.0">

Answer (score 6):

I faced some problem and the above solution worked. But what is the issue ? I run another project, but I don't do this import. But still it works properly.

I'm referring to this solution:

```
    <%@ page isELIgnored="false"%>
```

Comment: For me it was the wrong import that was causing this issue, i had mistakenly imported `import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;` using auto-import where I was supposed import `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;`.

Comment: above solution worked for me but what is the issue..I have imported the correct ModelAndView.

Answer (score 4):

I was mistakenly using the wrong import.

I got `import org.springframework.web.portlet.ModelAndView;` auto-imported when I thought I had `org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;` imported.

It almost drove me nuts.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Now consider you are using jsp 3.x or above.
And you are also using spring maven from spring.io repository.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>


<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>io.spring.repo.maven.release</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release/</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

you must check if maven library contains the tomcat-embeded-el.
if your are not using spring's embeded tomcat server, then please drop the above (tomcat-embeded-*) libraries or write new pom dependencies. 
like

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-context-support</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-expression</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
        <version>4.1.6.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>

<repositories>
    <repository>
        <id>io.spring.repo.maven.release</id>
        <url>http://repo.spring.io/release/</url>
        <snapshots><enabled>false</enabled></snapshots>
    </repository>
</repositories>
```

This should work!